# Firebase signInWithCredential giving error using Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase in iOS using swift language. I am trying to signIn with Facebook. I am getting FBSDKAccessToken using with graphRequest. When I am using Firebase  signIn method of Facebook then getting following error

```
 UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x608000059560 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)"
 UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
         code = 400;
         errors = (
             {
                 domain = global;
                 message = "Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook: {\"error\":{\"message\":\"(#4) Application request limit
 reached\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"is_transient\":true,\"code\":4,\"fbtrace_id\":\"En2h2Q0L7TP\"}}";
                 reason = invalid;
             }
         );
         message = "Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook: {\"error\":{\"message\":\"(#4) Application request limit
 reached\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"is_transient\":true,\"code\":4,\"fbtrace_id\":\"En2h2Q0L7TP\"}}";
     }}}, error_name=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for
 more information.}
```

And my complete code is

```
    {
        let login : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        login.logOut()
        login.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile","email"], fromViewController: self, handler:  { (result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                let request: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id,email,first_name,middle_name,last_name,picture"], HTTPMethod: "GET")
                request.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
                    if error == nil
                    {
                        let userDetail : NSDictionary = result as! NSDictionary




                    let token = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString

                       let credential =  FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(token)
                       FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential, completion: { (user, error) in

                            if error == nil
                            {

                                let homeVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageController") as? PageController
                                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeVC!, animated: true)

                                print(userDetail)
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                 print("Signing  Failed ")

                            }


                        })



                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("Error Getting Info \(error)");
                    }
                })
            }else{
                print("Login Failed")
            }
        })

        return;
    }
```

Comment: I have the same problem now, did you solve this in the end?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by change the **FacebookAppID** in info.plist and URL
I used the one which is unconnected with Firebase application. (old one)

this is my login flow
1) `fbLoginManager.login`
2) `let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)`
3) `Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential)`